# Laravel - Get belongsToMany relationships from an array of Id's

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

In Laravel 7 - I have the following relationships defined:

`Group.php`

```
public function services()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'service_group', 'group_id', 'service_id');
}
```

`Service.php`

```
public function groups()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'service_group', 'service_id', 'group_id');
}
```

With a pivot table of `service_group`

In my controller the user selects different `group` id's.
I then need to return all `services` of those groups.

If I just had a single group (id of 3 for example) selected I can do:

```
$services = Group::find(3)->services;
foreach($services as $service) {
  // ...
}
```

How would I go about getting all services from say an array of groups `[3, 7, 15]`
Is there a cleaner way than doing something like so...

```
// $groups = [3, 7, 15];
foreach($groups as $group_id) {
    $services = Group::find($group_id)->services;
    foreach($services as $service) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even better would be.

```php
$services = Service::whereHas('groups', function($query) use ($groups) {
    $query->whereIn('group_id', $groups);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findMany`. You shall also use eager loading to avoid making too many SQL queries. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

```
$allServices = Group::with('services')->findMany([3, 7, 15])->map(fn ($group) => $group->services)->flatten();

return $allServices;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `whereIn` method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array:

```php
$services = Group::whereIn('id', $groups)->with('services')->get();
```